# All imported generic issues are given a MEDIUM severity despite specifying rule severities

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am running SonarQube 10.3 and sonar-scanner 5.0.1.3006.
I would like to be able to define my own issue severities and have them displayed accordingly on the SonarQube UI, but it seems all issue severities are defaulting to MEDIUM.

I have this issue in a generic issue import format:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": "B307",
            "name": "eval - use of possible insecure function",
            "engineId": "bandit",
            "cleanCodeAttribute": "FORMATTED",
            "impacts": [
                {
                    "softwareQuality": "MAINTAINABILITY",
                    "severity": "HIGH"
                }
            ]
        },
        "issues": {
            {
            "engineId": "bandit",
            "ruleId": "B307",
            "primaryLocation": {
                "filePath": "/tmp/repo/bandit/main.py",
                "textRange": {
                    "startLine": 36,
                    "startColumn": 5
                },
                "message": "Use of possibly insecure function - consider using safer ast.literal_eval."
            }
        },
}
```

Why is it that when I import this issue, the severity shows up as MEDIUM?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by changing the `engineId` to one that isn’t recognized by SonarQube.

This behavior doesn't appear to be documented, but it seems SonarQube recognizes the `bandit` tool and tries to apply its own quality profiles which don't exist, then defaults to MEDIUM sev.